# How to filter out N number of items from an array randomly?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of colors, as such:

```
let colors = [
        [100, 200, 105, 255],
        [255, 143, 102, 255],
        ... etc
    ]
```

These colors are all generated by two dimensional image files (standard pngs and jpgs)

I am currently filtering out the duplicates as such:

```
colors = colors.filter((t = {}, a => !(t[a] = a in t)));
```

And now I want to go through the array of colors and pull out similar colors, within a certain range.

I have a filter as such:

```
var range = 60;
colors = colors.filter(
    (color, index, colors) => {
        var exclude = false;
        for (i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
            let ranged_r = color[0];
            let ranged_g = color[1];
            let ranged_b = color[2];
            if (colors[i][0] >= ranged_r - range && colors[i][0] <= ranged_r + range) {
                if (colors[i][1] >= ranged_g - range && colors[i][1] <= ranged_g + range) {
                    if (colors[i][2] >= ranged_b - range && colors[i][2] <= ranged_b + range) {
                        exclude = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return exclude;
    }
)
```

The problem is that this step is incredibly expensive. There are still hundreds of thousands of combinations by the time I am on this step. I'd like to add a preprocessing step where I, as efficiently as possible, cut the result set down to about 10% of what it is right now - maybe even 1% if there are a sufficient number of values (like over 100k).

Is there an efficient and fairly cheap way to do this "randomly" (doesn't have to be truly mathematically random, good enough is well.. good enough)

I suppose I could do something like this (pseudocode):

```
colors.randomSort() // sorts colors randomly with no order
colors.popABunchOff() // pops a bunch of values off of colors
```

What is the most efficient way in Javascript to pop up off X number of values randomly?

Comment: It is comparing each color against the whole array of colors. The filter determines if the individual color is put in the array. Inside the filter, I want to do one and only one check - if there's ANY reason to exclude - it should be excluded. The filter is working as intended. I just need to pare down the list before going through the filter.